# Alternate history/fantasy novel with a woman as Alexander the Great

Tags: story-identification, alternate-history

Can anyone identify a novel, probably from the '80s, which told the story of Alexander the Great but gender flipped to be a woman? The character's name was altered to be Aleksanr Alisond (or similar).

It was quite similar to Mary Gentle's "Story of Ash" but that's not it.

Comment: Community consensus appears to be that alternate history is sufficiently SF in and of itself to be on topic. Voting to leave open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Walk in the Dark" series by Alison Spedding

*The Road and the Hills*' (the first book) description:

> A reworking of the legend of Alexander the Great - with a female
>   protagonist. Ailixond, Lord of Safi, had taken his army across half
>   the known world to assuage his appetite for conquest. Never had he met
>   anyone like Aleizon Ailix Ayndra - a woman soldier who will one day
>   rule the known world.

[https://www.amazon.com/Road-Hills-Walk-Dark/dp/004823365X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/004823365X)

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much,  That's been bugging me for ages!